# Creating a pandas dataframe from numpy.ndarray inside a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am quite new to Python so I can't solve a trivial problem.
I need to create a composite line made up of straight lines connecting some points.
I have a txt file with a set of 2D (x-y) coordinate of the points. I correctly read the file and store the data in a dataframe. Then with a for loop I take two consecutive points and I find the coefficients (coefficients_i) of the lines passing through the points with the numpy function polyfit. Then I create the single segments of lines connecting the points (yaxis_i) but what I can't do is to create a single composite line made up of the different segments. My line should be: yaxis_i + yaxis_(i+1) + ... + yaxis_(i+n) and I would like it to be stored in a dataframe so that I can easily plot it. I tried to append the different segments into a numpy.ndarray but it does't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
d = []
e = []
for i in range(len(ln_pts)-1):
    x_i = [ln_pts.iat[i+1,0],ln_pts.iat[i,0]]
    y_i = [ln_pts.iat[i+1,1],ln_pts.iat[i,1]]
    coefficients_i = np.polyfit(x_i, y_i, 1)    
    print('m',i,' =', coefficients_i[0])
    print('q',i,' =', coefficients_i[1])
    
    # Compute the values of the lines (yaxis) in a given domain (xaxis)
    polynomial_i = np.poly1d(coefficients_i)
    xaxis_i = np.arange(x_i[1],x_i[0])
    yaxis_i = polynomial_i(xaxis_i)
    d.append(xaxis_i)
    e.append(yaxis_i)
```

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Don't the points you read from the file already describe the line as you want it? Why the shenanigans with polynomial fits?

Comment: If you want to increase the density of points, a simple [interpolation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) should be all you need.

Comment: Also, please format your code correctly. Incorrectly indented python code is invalid python code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to create the polynomial fits and then interpolate at a denser collection of `x` values. This operation is called *piecewise linear interpolation*. Numpy already has an `interp()` that does this for you.

Unless you're using pandas downstream, there's no need to bring pandas into the equation either.

```
pts = np.loadtxt('myfile.txt')
wanted_xpts = np.linspace(pts[:, 0].min(), pts[:, 0].max(), 10000)
interp_ypts = np.interp(wanted_xpts, pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1])

plt.plot(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], 'or')
plt.plot(wanted_xpts, interp_ypts, '-k')
plt.show()
```

Do you *absolutely have to* use a loop? This is unnecessary and inefficient, but here you go anyway:

Your code is mostly fine for this job. There's no need to calculate a polynomial fit. You can just use `interp` with `x_i` and `y_i`.

```
d, e = [], []
for i in range(len(ln_pts)-1):
    x_i = [ln_pts.iat[i+1,0],ln_pts.iat[i,0]]
    y_i = [ln_pts.iat[i+1,1],ln_pts.iat[i,1]]
    xaxis_i = np.linspace(x_i[1], x_i[0], 10)
    yaxis_i = np.interp(xaxis_i, x_i, y_i)
    d.append(xaxis_i)
    e.append(yaxis_i)
```

Now you have all the new x and y points from each segment in individual lists in `d` and `e`. You can simply use `np.hstack` to stack all these into a single 1-D array.

```
xpts = np.hstack(d)
ypts = np.ystack(e)
```

You can then assign these to dataframe columns if you like.

Comment: Thank you, very useful indeed but it remains the problem of the for-loop. I need to implement a for loop which does the job for each couple of points and merge the results into a single vector.

Comment: @EnricoB _Why?_ Unless it's an exercise, there's really no reason to do it that way. Appending to numpy arrays is a slow operation, if you can do it in one shot (like you can in this case) you should.

Comment: Ok now I finally got it. It seems to work fine. Thank you for your help Pranav